# Python Data Model : confused again with classmethod

Tags: python, python-datamodel

It's said that :

> When it would yield a class method object, it is transformed into a
>   bound user-defined method object whose im_class and im_self attributes
>   are both C.

in the [Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

And I did an EX.

```
>>> class C(object) :
...     @classmethod
...     def cm(cls) : print cls
... 
>>> C.cm
<bound method type.cm of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> C.cm.im_self
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> C.cm.im_class
<type 'type'>
```

It's not hard for me to understand the phenomenon. But unfortunately, in the reference, it's told that im_self should be **the same** as im_class. How to explain the inconsistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that the same way you do. It appears that what Python is actually doing is not exactly what the documentation says.

It sets `im_self` to the class, and `im_class` to the class's type, i.e., its metaclass. The default metaclass for classes in Python is `type`. This is analogous to what happens with methods that are bound to instances: `im_self` is the instance and `im_class` is the type of the instance. In the case of `@classmethod`, in other words, the class is treated as the instance (which it is; it's an instance of `type`).

Possibly the behavior was changed without the documentation being updated, or the documentation was just wrong to begin with. I write documentation for a living and I can confirm that it is almost impossible to keep it 100% correct for something the size of Python -- especially for obscure details like this one.

The Python developers have a procedure for reporting bugs in the documentation. [Give it a try](http://docs.python.org/bugs.html#documentation-bugs)!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I've sent an e-mail to the developers. Hope they will reply soon!

Comment: I haven't had any response since I sent it out. Could you plz send one?